# Is it possible to setup remixJs for supertest?

Tags: supertest, remix.run

I really felt in love with using [Remix](https://remix.run). But what I'm missing right now is to run integration tests via e. g. [supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest).

For example [NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/) offers a method called [Test.createTestingModule()](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing#end-to-end-testing) which can easily used by `supertest` to unit test parameter validation or even database actions.

Because it uses the source files under the hood it even supports the line-coverage functionality from e. g. [Jest](https://jestjs.io).

Is it possible setup Remix for supertest?